# Create and initialise a time column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I need to add a time column to my existing dataframe and initialize it. I tried this line of code `df['date']=datetime.time(0, 0, 0)` in a small script :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[34,54,32,23,26]})
df['date']=datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
print(df['date'])
```

**output:**

```
0    00:00:00
1    00:00:00
2    00:00:00
3    00:00:00
4    00:00:00
```

but when I implemented it in my code, in which I work on large dataframes, I got this error:

```
dfreez['delta']=datetime.time(0, 0, 0)

TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to 'int' object
```

this is a piece of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
dfreez = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx',header=0, index= False)
from datetime import datetime
dfreez['delta']=datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
```

I don't understand what went wrong!

Comment: Don't do `datetime.time`, do `pd.to_timedelta('00:00:00')`.

Answer (score 1):

`import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime` and **not** the same.

After the first one, the local `datetime` variable is a reference to the module. So you can access the `datetime` class with `datetime.datetime` and the `time` class with `datetime.time`

After the second, the local `datetime` variable is a reference to the `datetime` class. So you have no (direct *) way to access the `time` class.

You should just use:

```
import datetime
```

in the second snippet just like what was done in first one.

---

(*) FYI: it is still possible with the **ugly** `sys.modules['datetime'].time`. But never pretend that I advised you to do that!